# SQL Statement with multiple SET's to update table

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, vba

Hi guys I have some code that updates Access fields from Excel, it works fine when I only want to update one value (`MonitorCapacity`), however I now want it to update multiple values e.g. a field called `MonitorSiteref`, it will have the same `WHERE` - so when the `Monitor_Siteref = '" & strID & "'"` I'm not to sure where to start with this as I'm relatively new to SQL, what I've already got is:

```
strID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 66).Value


cnn.Execute "UPDATE Tbl_Primary SET MonitorCapacity = " & _
IIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 74).Value2 = "", "Null", _
"'" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 74).Value2 & "'") & _
" WHERE Monitor_Siteref = '" & strID & "'"`
```

**Next Edit:**

```
cnn.Execute "UPDATE Tbl_Primary " & _
"SET MonitorCapacity = " & IIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 74).Value2 = "", "Null", _
"'" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 74).Value2 & "'"), _
"Monitor_Permnumber = " & IIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 73).Value2 = "", "Null", _
"'" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 73).Value2 & "'") & _
" WHERE Monitor_Siteref = '" & strID & "'"

lngRow = lngRow + 1
```

Comment: How's MySQL used here? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL Update syntax goes like this:

```
    update <TABLE> set <COLUMN> = <VALUE>, 
                       <COLUMN> = <VALUE> where <COND>;
```

So i guess you want to comma separate your column,value tupels.

You also may want to put your logic outside of the statement creation. That would make it far more readable.

Check this for further explanations: [UPDATE Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: I've tried something like that, it doesnt work just populates every single field in `MonitorCapacity` with the same answer, please see edited answer.

Comment: What you are doing in your edit is: Update TABLE set COLUMN = VALUE, update TABLE set COLUMN = value. You need the "update TABLE set " part only once

Comment: Hi, I realised that, tried without the UPDATE, same problem (new code above)

Comment: Hi again @Matze sorry to be a bit of a nuesense but I'm struggling to get my head around this, I've again added my latest code.

Comment: Doesn't look too bad. I have no VBA experience at all, so that long statements are really confusing. You should really try to calculate the values beforehand. Also, as eggyal mentioned, you should use prepared statements. That adds not only a lot more security but also readability. Try writing the update statement explicitly until it works or print the statement string to stdout (to see what it looks like after processing). Then add the variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building an update statement with multiple columns to update MSQL with VBA.  Here's my simple code.  I'm parsing a variable in function to execute SQL command:

```
Function GetUpdateTextSQL(PIC As String, Customer As String, DOB As Date, 
                          Rank As String, Organization As String, 
                          Status As String, Gender As String, 
                          Religion As String, Hobby As String, 
                          CreatedBy1 As String, CreatedOn1 As Date, 
                          ChangedBy1 As String, ChangedOn1 As Date, 
                          PeopleID As Integer) As String

           Dim SQLStr As String

           SQLStr = "UPDATE People" & _
                    "SET PIC = " & _
                    "'" & PIC & "', Customer = '" & Customer & "'," & _
                    "DOB = '" & Format(DOB, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "',_
                    Rank = '" & Rank & "'," & _
                    "Organization = '" & Organization & "',Status = '" &_ 
                    Status & "', Gender = '" & Gender & "'," & _
                    "Religion = '" & Religion & "', Hobby = '" & Hobby &_ 
                    "'," & _
                    "CreatedBy = '" & CreatedBy1 & "', CreatedOn = '" &_ 
                    CreatedOn1 & "'," & _
                    "ChangedBy = '" & ChangedBy1 & "', ChangedOn = '" &_ 
                    ChangedOn1 & "'" & _
                    "WHERE PeopleID =  & PeopleID &;"

           GetUpdateTextSQL = SQLStr
```

The error I get is that 'Incorrect Syntax Near PIC'.  What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you *really* should be passing values as prepared statement parameters.  Why?  Read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

For example:

```
Dim siteref As String = _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 66).Value

Dim capacity As String = _
    capacity = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Cells(lngRow, 74).Value2

If capacity = "" Then capacity = Nothing

Dim stmt As New ADODB.Command
With stmt
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Prepared = True
    .CommandText = _
        "UPDATE Tbl_Primary " & _
        "SET    MonitorCapacity = ? " & _
        "WHERE  Monitor_Siteref = ?"

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
        "MonitorCapacity", _
        adVarChar, _
        adParamInput, _
        Len(capacity), _
        capacity _
    )

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
        "Monitor_Siteref", _
        adVarChar, _
        adParamInput, _
        Len(siteref), _
        siteref _
    )

    .Execute
End With
```

Then, to answer your actual question, just add multiple terms to the `SET` clause (delimited by comma):

```
    .CommandText = _
        "UPDATE Tbl_Primary " & _
        "SET    MonitorCapacity = ?, " & _
        "       OtherColumn = ? " & _
        "WHERE  Monitor_Siteref = ?"
```

Obviously you will also need to add additional parameters to the command.

Comment: HI @eggyal, i tried your second code format and still no luck? Please see my edited answer for how my current code looks..